# Meteor.js facebook login with 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable'

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor

I'm working on a small personal project, where a user can login with Facebook via Meteor.js' built in `{{loginButtons}}`
But the problem is, when running the app in full screen via `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` there's no popup dialog asking for permission. The screen just goes blank.

I am NOT using facebook's sdk at all.

It works fine in mobile safari. I've deployed it to meteor for some final testing, so it's no localhost issue.

Is this possible without having to create my own user creation, and/or server side implementation, and/or facebook's sdk?
Eventually I plan on add more, like twitter and google.

Also, I'm still using iOS 6.1

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE, see my other answer for a much improved example

So I just spent about an hour figuring some stuff out.
I think the best thing to do is drop Meteor's built in account system
Instead I'm using 'oauth.io' (no affiliation) and 'meteor router' and I'm going to create users with Meteor's Accounts.createUser();
The best part about this, is that it works with localhost and my iPhone, so i don't have to keep deploying it to test.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    OAuth.initialize('my key');
});
```

My route:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/oauth': function() {
      console.log('oauthed');
        OAuth.callback('facebook', function(err, result) {
            var token = result.access_token;
            var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='+token;

            $.get( url, function( data ) {
                alert(data.email)
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Then a simple anchor

```
$('#loginfb').live('click', function() {
    OAuth.redirect('facebook', "/oauth");
});
```

Thats as far as I've gotten, but it works with `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`
I'm able to authenticate and get my Facebook info.
Its more work than I wanted to do, but not too difficult.

So I was thinking about doing something like getting the user's email with this method, and then using:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    email: data.email, 
    password: data.id //since your Facebook id can't change
});
```

That way the user can change it or reset it later on or I can prompt them to change it.

Then I gotta check if that user exists,(not sure how to do this) and if they exist then do:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(data.email, data.id);
```

Ok. So I tweaked my setup a little bit.

I had to switch to Backbone Router, for some reason Meteor Router would refresh the page twice every time it loaded /oauth.
Backbone doesn't.

I added a server side function for generating a password.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({
      pushState: true,
      root: "/"
  });

  OAuth.initialize('key goes here');
});

var $Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "/": "home",
    "oauth": "oauth",
    "": "home"
  },
  home: function () {
    console.log('home')
  },
  oauth: function () {
    OAuth.callback('facebook', function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      var token = result.access_token;
      var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + token;
      $.get(url, function (data) {
        var email = data.email;
        var pass = Meteor.call('generatePass', data, function (error, result) {
          Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, result, function (error) {
            if (error) {
              var options = {};
              options.email = email;
              options.password = pass;
              Accounts.createUser(options, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  $router.navigate('/');
                } else {
                  //Account creation successful return to index
                  $router.navigate('/');
                }
              })
            } else {
              //Login successful return to index
              $router.navigate('/');
            }
          });
        });
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
});

var $router = new $Router();
// I use jquery for events, I don't like to use meteor's template event handlers.

$('#loginfb').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //have to use redirect, otherwise popup won't work correctly since we're using mobile-webapp-capable
  OAuth.redirect('facebook', "/oauth");
});


//server.js
Meteor.methods({
  generatePass: function (data) {
    // .. do stuff ..
    var pass = fancy function that creates a password based on the supplied data;
    return pass;
  }
});
```

So far it only works with Facebook, and its not very well tested.
Id love some guidance, and/or constructive criticism.

Comment: I'm currently rewriting my app to make it better. And in doing so I wanted to figure out a better way to create a login with Facebook. This update is also using Iron-router instead of backbone. I just figured out how to use Meteor's `Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService` and Meteor's built in 'login' rather than trying to see if a user exists, and if so login, else create a user then login. This new way also uses less code. So once I clean it up i'll write up another answer. and I no longer have to 'generate' password

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the oauth packages use window.open to open a popup window. I have no experience using apple-mobile-web-app-capable before but some research seems to suggest that window.open does not work with it. The solution would seem to be testing if the client is using a fullscreen app which is possible using

```
window.navigator.standalone
```

according to https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Unfortunately the oauth login workflow is kind of awkward in assuming that a popup has been opened. I'm unsure where the best place to do this test is and whether or not a login or user creation will be attempted after the user enters their username/password in the new window.

I tried changing the window.open method to window.location in accounts-oauth-helper/oauth_client.js and it does then open the window but I was having issues with my redirect_uri probably because I was doing this on a localhost project from my phone and so I'm unsure if the login process will continue once the login has happened.

It seems likely that this will affect all login providers when using apple-mobile-web-app-capable and so this is probably a bug that needs to be fixed. I'll try setting up a project later to get a better look at this and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a much better way to do this without using accounts-facebook and without using facebook's own sdk
But I am using meteor's accounts and accounts-ui(not that I really need it, its just convenient)

Event handler on the client

```
Template.header.events({
  'click #loginFB': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   OAuth.redirect('facebook', "/oauthlink");
 //or 
    var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' +client_id+'&response_type=token&redirect_uri='+redirect;
window.location = url;
  }
});
```

Iron Router's route that catches the result from OAuth

```
this.route('oauthLink', {
path: '/oauthlink',
action: function() {
  OAuth.callback('facebook', function(err, result) {
    Meteor.call('fblogin', result, function(error, result) {
      Meteor.loginWithToken(result.token, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          Meteor._debug("Error logging in with token: " + err);
        }
      })
    });
  });
}
```

});

or without oauth.io

```
this.route('oauthLink', {
path: '/oauthlink',
action: function() {
  var str = window.location.hash;
  str = str.split('&');
  var accessToken = str[0];
  var expiresIn = str[1];
  accessToken = accessToken.split('=');
  expiresIn = expiresIn.split('=');
  var result = {
    access_token : accessToken[1],
    expires_in : expiresIn[1]
  };
  Meteor.call('fblogin', result, function(error, result) {
    console.log(result)
    Meteor.loginWithToken(result.token, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        Meteor._debug("Error logging in with token: " + err);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

});

Not sure if 'Action' is the correct function (i'm new to iron-router), but it works.

And then on the server

```
Meteor.methods({
  fblogin: function(response) {
    var identity = Meteor.call('$getIdentity', response.access_token);
    // synchronous call to get the user info from Facebook

    var serviceData = {
      accessToken: response.access_token,
      expiresAt: (+new Date) + (1000 * response.expires_in)
    };
    // include all fields from facebook
    // http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/
    var whitelisted = ['id', 'email', 'name', 'first_name',
        'last_name', 'link', 'username', 'gender', 'locale', 'age_range'];

    var fields = _.pick(identity, whitelisted);
    _.extend(serviceData, fields);

    var stuff = {
        serviceName : 'facebook',
        serviceData: serviceData,
        options: {profile: {name: identity.name}}
      };
      var userData = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService(stuff.serviceName, stuff.serviceData, stuff.options);

      var x = DDP._CurrentInvocation.get();

      var token = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
      Accounts._insertLoginToken(userData.userId, token);
      Accounts._setLoginToken(userData.userId, x.connection, Accounts._hashLoginToken(token.token))
      x.setUserId(userData.userId)


      return {
        id: userData.userId,
        token: token.token,
        tokenExpires: Accounts._tokenExpiration(token.when)
      };

  },
  $getIdentity: function(accessToken) {
    try {
      return HTTP.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me", {
        params: {access_token: accessToken}}).data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw _.extend(new Error("Failed to fetch identity from Facebook. " + err.message),
               {response: err.response});
        }
    }
});
```

Pretty much all of fblogin() is actually from Meteor's own accounts-facebook package. 
I just modified it to fit my needs.
$getIdentity is a verbatim copy from there.

var stuff contains the Facebook data (name, access token, and so on), and meteor account data, and puts it into Accounts.updateorcreateuserfromexternalservice, which builds your meteor account 
fblogin() returns userData, which it gets from Accounts.updateorcreate.... and from that you  get your token, which you use to login in via Metoer.loginWithToken.

All this happens without opening up a new window or tab like it would if i were using accounts-facebook. Thus fixing the main issue i had, and as an added bonus, it seems to be functionally equivalent to using accounts-facebook.
No more checking to see if a user exists, and if so login, with a 'generated password', or if they don't exists, create them and then login with a 'generated password'

Naturally this can be expanded upon for other oauth apis and you obviously don't need oauth.io. Im just lazy.
Hopefully someone else finds this useful.

Comment: Update as of April 9 2014, it seems 0.8.0 changed a few things. So i had to update my code to get it to work again. I had a look at their source on github for accounts-base/accounts_server.js and figured it out. I'll update the code above to reflect the necessary changes